# In D3 how do you add labels to features in geojson feature collection

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, geojson

D3 is being used to render geojson feature collection [here](https://github.com/SimonbJohnson/iD/blob/master/js/id/renderer/gpx_layer.js).  Only one svg element is generated for the feature collection under "path". When I try to generate the labels I get one label for the whole collection.  How do I generate the labels for each feature in the collection instead?

Sample code which will generate the label for the feature collection instead of every feature. (Also does not appear centered on the feature collection)

```
paths.enter().append('text').attr('d', d3.geo.path().projection(projection)).text('hello world');
```

Comment: The code you've linked to seems to be for rendering GPX and not GeoJSON. In particular, it assumes that everything is one path and one feature, hence you only get one label.

Comment: The GPX is converted to GeoJSON before it is used by the d3 functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing in the feature collection, the array of features should be passed as explained [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#wiki-_path).

To position the labels correctly [path.centroid(feature)](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#wiki-path_centroid) can be used.